# In what year was it revealed that Wolverine has an adamantium skeleton?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine, adamantium

When did readers learn that Wolverine has such feature? Was it known from the very first appearance of Wolverine in 'The Incredible Hulk #180' from October 1974?

Comment: He only appears in [the final panel](http://i57.fastpic.ru/big/2013/1108/e3/bee95c2d8d4f381cdcd30a5a8d7dece3.jpg) of Hulk #180.

Comment: @Valorum don't get it could you describe better what you mean ?

Comment: @RS Valorum is correct.  Hulk #180 was his first appearance in the last panel of Hulk 180.  In Hulk #181 was his first full debut, showing the battle between Hulk, Wolverine and Wendigo.

Comment: @kelzak What do you mean by FULL debut - Adamantium endoskeleton was revealed ? And what is 'panel' ?

Comment: @RS In Hulk 180 Wolverine is only in 1 panel vs in #181 Wolverine appears in just about every page.  As for his Adamantium anatomy this was revealed in X-Men#98 (April 1976).

Comment: RS - bordering on 'unclear what you are asking' vote to close from me. The question in the title is different from the question in the text. Which is it? '**When was it revealed that he had an adamanitum skeleton?**', or, '**was he shown to have an adamantium skeleton in his debut?**' - two different questions.  @Valorum answered the question in the text, but kelzak answered the question in the title

Comment: @NKCampbell pardon, fixed.

Comment: I've rolled back. There's absolutely nothing wrong with the question as originally worded. It shows what research you've already done.

Comment: @NKCampbell - I don't see how they're any different and a competent answer would deal with both sub-questions anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### TL;DR. We find out that his skeleton is made from adamantium in [**The Uncanny X-Men #126**](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/X-Men_Vol_1_126) from 1979.

---

Wolverine's first appearance was a single panel cameo at the end of [The 
Incredible Hulk #180](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Incredible_Hulk_Vol_1_180).

[image]

There's no mention of adamantium until the following edition, [The Incredible Hulk #181](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Incredible_Hulk_Vol_1_181), where we learn that his *claws* are made from the substance.

[image]

Interestingly, in the same issue he takes a blow to the head which he's described as surviving only due to his "*astonishing speed and stamina*". No mention is made of an adamantium *skeleton*

[image]

It wasn't until [X-Men #98](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/X-Men_Vol_1_98) that they're revealed to be part of his body (as opposed to part of his suit).

[image]

---

In [X-Men #124](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/X-Men_Vol_1_124) we learn that Wolverine has "unbreakable bones"[image]

and in [The Uncanny X-Men #126](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/X-Men_Vol_1_126) we finally discover that his ***bones*** are made out of a metal called adamantium

[image]

Comment: I don't have a source, but I seem to recall that the class were originally planned as part of the suit,and they changed it later.  Small difference, but interesting I thought.

Comment: So Wolverine got jacked by a huge man...

Comment: Surviving Hulk's punch to the head will mostly be because of his healing factor, I think.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - My instinct is that they didn't decide that his skeleton was made of adamantium until much later. There's a panel in an earlier comic where they changed it from him getting shot in the stomach to getting grazed because they didn't think audiences would buy that he could heal from it fast enough to survive. It wasn't until much later that his healing went from 'faster than a human's" to "insanely fast"